# Rails Validation Errors not being displayed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, error-handling

For some reason my validation errors are being picked up but are not displaying on the page as I would like below is my model and the new view. I will also attach a picture of my validation error being picked up but not displaying in the view.

```
Model

class Review < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :tea

  validates :title, presence: true
  validates :rating, numericality: {only_integer: true, greater_than_or_equal_to: 0, less_than: 11}
  validates :tea, uniqueness: {scope: :user, message: "has already been reviewed by you" }

  scope :order_by_rating, ->{group(:id).order('avg(reviews.rating) desc')}
end
```

```
View
<h1>Write a Review for  </h1>

<%= form_for Review.new do |f|%>
    <% if @review.errors.any? %>
        <h2>Errors:</h2>
        <ul>    
            <% @review.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
            <li><%= message %></li>
           <% end %> 
        </ul>
    <% end %>
```

[image: Validation Error]

Comment: You'd probably want to use `save` instead of `save!`

Comment: I think it is because you are using `save!`.

Comment: I totally missed that I still had save! working on another branch I had forgotten that was there thank you!

Comment: You're also using `<%= form_for Review.new do |f|%>` instead of `<%= form_for @review do |f|%>`. With the former any user input is lost.

Answer (score 2):

In Ruby  there is a convention that methods ending with `!` denote a "dangerous" method. The method either mutates its receiver or raises an exception. `ActiveRecord::Persistence` has both normal and "dangerous" methods:

- `save` and `save!`
- `create` and `create!`
- `update` and `update!`

The later raises an `ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid` exception if any of the validations fail. This is really useful when you're creating records from a seed file, in your tests or inside a transaction.

But when you are  normally handling user input you want to use the normal `save` method as invalid input is just a fact of life and not an exceptional event. If you rely on changing the code to `.save!` for debugging you should really learn to use pry or byebug instead to step into the code.

You should also fix the form so that you're binding it to the `@review` instance variable so that the users input is not erased. Nobody likes badly implemented forms that makes them retype everything.

```
<%= form_for @review.new do |f|%>
  # ...
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

.save! was not allowing the view to render errors as shown adjusting create method allows errors to be displayed.

The main reason for this is the rails `bang (!) methods` are used to raise errors rather than just handling and passing it.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't getting errors on the object because you're calling a version of save that raises exceptions.

Check out the documentation on `#save!` vs `#save`: https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/save%21

This isn't a great place to use `#save!` instead, you should do things with `#save` like:

```rb
if @review.save
  # redirect
else
  # You can now access the `#errors` method if you want
  errors = @review.errors
end
```

Read this for more info on ActiveRecord error handling: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Errors.html